# Best way to remove "wound closure" tape that is taped to some of my eyebrow?

Tags: medicine

I've got 2 *CVSHealth Wound Closure Adhesive Surgical Tape Strips* taped to much of one eyebrow to cover a gash I suffered just slightly above the eyebrow.

I've always used the bikini wax method for removing medical tape. But, because the skin around the eye is so loose and the condition of the gash is unknown, bikini waxing it is not an option.

How can I get this tape off my eyebrow with minimal stripping motion?

Comment: U taped the eyebrow?  You should shaved it.

Comment: @paparazzi Someone else dressed the gash while saying "this probably needs stitches". I need to take a look for myself now.

Comment: They don't typically stitch after 12 hours.  If it is not bleeding then it is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always used baby oil for removing adhesive bandages. It eliminates the adhesive like magic. However, I've never used it on that particular kind of tape, so you should try it out first. Get some more of the tape, if you can, and experiment first on another part of your body (like your forearm, especially if you have hair there so it is similar to your eyebrow).